create static library of files with .inl extension
I am trying to create a static library of files with .inl extension, but getting failed. If I change the extension to .cpp then it builds.
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(CarSimulator VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_library(printer
   print.inl print.hpp
)
set_property(TARGET printer PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

print.hpp
#ifndef PRINT_H
#define PRINT_H

template<typename T>
void print(const T& t);

#include "print.cpp"

#endif

print.inl
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void print(const T& t) {
   std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

Error
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "printer".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: printer
-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.


Looks like a header only library consisting of templates with the implementations in .inl files that the headers include. There's nothing to make a library out of, you need all of those files at compile time for any program that uses them.

CMake adding C++ header only libraries may help.

CMake has some predefined rules for the determining the linker-language based on the source files extension.
.cpp is a known extension for C++, but aparently .inl isn't.
You can use the following command to set the language explicitly to C++:
set_target_properties(printer PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

Having said that it seems like your library is actually a header only one:
In order to consume it in another project you only need to use #include print.hpp (which in turn #includes the .inl file).
If this is indeed the case - it is not clear why you need a CMake for it at all: you can simply deliver the source files as is.

First, Thanks for this answer. I have a doubt related to the above header only library line, this means there is no use in creating a library if my library code contains only templates. If that's the case, I would like to know whether the C++ STL library is also a header only library? as it makes use of only templates.

@Harry I'm not 100% sure about STL. Despite the name it could (theroretically) contain some source files for non-template parts. But what I am positive is: if you do have a real header only library (which makes sense if you have only templates) then yes - you don't need anything else but these sources (and you need to distribute all the sources anyway).

@Harry You can actually verify this issue about your library quire easily: start a new test application project that uses your library, and make the library sources available for #includes (via the configured include-paths). If it's enough for your test project to build and run - then your library is truely a header only one. In any case if it is not - you can configure CMake as I explained above.

@Harry The Standard Template Library, "STL", was a library developed by Alexander Stepanov before there even was a C++ standard. Parts of the C++ standard library are heavily influenced by it, but is not the same thing.
